# how to put a link to my ftp server on 12.04 desktop?

Tags: 12.04, ftp

How do I put a link to my ftp server on my desktop so when I drag and drop or copy and paste files to? I want to be able to move files off my system when needed. I did this on my 10.04 install with ease but 12.04 I can not figure out how to go about doing it.??? thanks everyone for any and all help..

Comment: Nice question. Maybe you could describe how you did this on 10.04?

Comment: I really can not remember how I did it. I do remember it was not hard todo. But that was with gnome 2 and I am still working on unity.